# I wanted to print something when given two numbers gives remainder 0 in python. The following code is to demonstrate what I want but it didn't worked

Tags: python

```
A = '4'
B = '2'
while True:
    if A % B == 0:
        print("True")
```

Comment: You are assigning the variables A and B as strings and then operating on them, you need to typecast them as integers first.

Answer (score 2):

It'll not gonna work as `A` and `B` are of string data-type. You can't just evaluate the `%` operator on string values you need to convert the values in suitable data types 1st.

```
A = '4'
B = '2'
while True:
    if int(A) % int(B) == 0:
        print("True")
```

Answer (score 1):

The variables `A` and `B` should be integers.
By declaring them in this way `A = '4'` declares them as strings.
But without the single inverted-commas, the variable is declared as an integer, like `A = 4`.

Use double equals sign for checking, single equals will assign the RHS value to LSH:

So, the code would be:

```py
A= 4
B = 2
if A % B == 0:
    print("True")
```